# Not able to connect Bot with skype for business

Tags: botframework

Want to implement [this](https://branch-blog.qlik.com/qlikbotnode-for-microsoft-skype-a59eae9ed736)

Created a Azure bot

Steps I followed:

1) By Creating resource in azure portal.

2) Created a bot channel registration.

3) Given name and added url of my qlik server.

4) Created environment variables as

```
- SKYPE_BOT_ID_SCV=’appid’
- SKYPE_BOT_PASSWORD_SVC=’password’
```

5) Added skype for business in channels

6) Tried with [this](https://skypeappregistration.azurewebsites.net/bot/39beda3a-60b8-4c3c-a8bb-620fc6af64f2) to connect with skype for business

**Error:**

> Get-CsPowerShellEndpoint : Unable to connect to the remote server

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that this bot solution is intended to work with Skype for Business? Their documentation does not mention this channel, see here https://github.com/qlik-bots/QlikBotNode : Telegram Telegram / Microsoft Skype / MS Teams / MS Cortana / Slack / Google Assistant / Amazon's Alexa

Comment: I'm not sure. So, it will work only Skype? I will check with Microsoft Skype.